# R crop raster data and set axis limits

Tags: r, dictionary, raster

With your help in another thread I have managed to plot some global maps. First I convert meteorological GRIB2 data to Netcdf and then plot the global maps.

Now I want to plot just a subregion of the map. I have tried crop command and succesfully extracted the subregion of the global nc file. But when plotting I can't find how to control axis limits. It plots a map bigger than data region so big white spaces appear on both sides.

This is the script I'm using to plot maps

```
library("ncdf")
library("raster")
library("maptools")

DIA=format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d00") # Data d'avui
url=sprintf("ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.%s/gfs.t00z.pgrb2f00", DIA) # Ruta del ftp
loc=file.path(sprintf("%s",url))
download.file(loc,"gfs.grb",mode="wb")

system("/usr/bin/grib2/wgrib2/wgrib2 -s gfs.grb | grep :TMP: | /usr/bin/grib2/wgrib2/wgrib2 -i gfs.grb -netcdf temp.nc",intern=T)

t2m <- raster("temp.nc", varname = "TMP_2maboveground")
rt2m <- rotate(t2m)
t2mc=rt2m-273.15

DAY=format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d") # Data d'avui

e=extent(-40,40,20,90)
tt=crop(t2mc,e)

png(filename="gfs.png",width=700,height=600,bg="white")    
    rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("snow1","snow2","snow3","seagreen","orange","firebrick"), space = "rgb")#colors
    plot(tt,col=rgb.palette(200),main=as.expression(paste("Temperatura a 2m ",DAY," + 00 UTC",sep="")),axes=T)
dev.off()
```

that give this output.

[image: cropped plot]

It has to be a simple one but I am a simple R user. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: New output when adding xlim=c(-40,40),ylim=c(20,90) as suggested. It seems it does not fix the problem. But playing with x,y size of the output png file looks promising as I can adjust size to fit the map.For sure it has to be another solution, the right one I can't find.

[image]

Comment: Just add an `xlim` and a `ylim` to your `plot` commands, e.g. `plot(.... , xlim = c(-10,30) , ylim = c(30 , 80 ) )` And nice plot by the way, +1

Comment: Maybe take a look at the googleVis package. Not sure it will help but it is pretty neat. It contains IntensityMap, GeoMap and Map functions that could perhaps help.

Comment: Hi @SimonO101 That was my first attempt before looking at crop, not sure if tried both. Not at work now, will give a try. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GeoffreyAbsalom Hi and thanks. I've got some scripts using raster so I prefer not to try another package. But heard a lot of googleVis, should be in my whish list. Thanks again.

Comment: You have to specify your png canvas size accordingly. E.g. `png(width=200,height=600, ... ) `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After downloading the data file, I can read directly with
raster. I choose band 221 that (if I am not wrong) it is what you
need according to
[this table](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/gfs/gfs.t00z.pgrb2f00.shtml):

```
library("raster")
t2mc <- raster('gfs.grb', band=221)

> t2mc
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 221  (of  315  bands)
dimensions  : 361, 720, 259920  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -0.25, 359.75, -90.25, 90.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +no_defs 
data source : /home/oscar/gfs.grb 
names       : gfs
```

You don't need the whole extent so you use `crop` to get the
desired extent:

```
e <- extent(-40,40,20,90)
tt <- crop(t2mc,e)
```

I have tried to display the `tt` raster with `plot` without
success. However, it works correctly with `spplot` if you use a
different extent (89.5 instead of 90):

```
e <- extent(-40,40,20,89.5)
tt <- crop(t2mc,e)

spplot(tt)
```

Now we have to add the administrative boundaries:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(maptools)

ext <- as.vector(e)
boundaries <- map('worldHires',
                  xlim=ext[1:2], ylim=ext[3:4],
                  plot=FALSE)
boundaries <- map2SpatialLines(boundaries,
                               proj4string=CRS(projection(tt)))
```

and change the palette:

```
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("snow1","snow2","snow3","seagreen","orange","firebrick"),
                                space = "rgb")

spplot(tt, col.regions=rgb.palette,
       colorkey=list(height=0.3),
       sp.layout=list('sp.lines', boundaries, lwd=0.5))
```

[image: spplot result]

If you prefer the `latticeExtra::layer` approach, you can achieve
a similar result with this code:

```
library(rasterVis)
levelplot(tt, col.regions=rgb.palette,
          colorkey=list(height=.3)) +
    layer(sp.lines(boundaries, lwd=0.5))
```

Comment: Gracias @oscar-perpinan Your suggestion works fine. I'm gonna look for additional spplot options for the axis, title and so on... Thanks

Comment: I will still look for a solution with plot.