# R: plot a geotiff multiband image as a background (spplot)

Tags: r, gis, raster

i'm trying to plot a multiband tiff file (aerial photo) behind a rastergrind with spplot:

```
aerial <- raster/stack/brick("path to .tif-file")
spplot(pred,zcol="ph",colorkey=list(space="left")) + as.layer(spplot(aerial))
```

the problem is now that the aerial photo is not right colored. it is a multiband file but spplot only take the first band (red). Is there a way to tell spplot to take the three color-bands for coloring?

greets
Elser

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: possibly duplicated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225644/640783